# saving dataframe to CSV in python 2

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am attempting to save a dataframe to Csv. When I print the dataframe it produces the output Im looking for, but when I save the dataframe to csv I only get the last line of the dataframe saved to the csv file..  what I have attempted so far.....

```
Index_tickers = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\\Index_list\\Index_tickers.csv')
Ticker = Index_tickers.ticker



for ticker in Index_tickers.ticker:    
    index_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\\Index_list\\' + ticker + '_1.csv')
    mkt_data = index_data[['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
    numRow = 2

    while numRow < endRow:
        dOpen0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Open']
        dHigh0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'High']
        dLow0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Low']
        dClose0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Close']
        dDate0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Date']
        dTime0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Time']
        dTicker0 = index_data.ix[numRow, 'Ticker']

        dHaClose0 = (dOpen0 + dHigh0 + dLow0 + dClose0) / 4
        dClose1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow -2  , 'Close']
        dOpen1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow -2  , 'Open']
        dHaOpen0 = (dClose1 + dOpen1) / 2 
        dHaHigh0 = max(dHigh0, dHaOpen0, dHaClose0)
        dHaLow0 = min(dLow0, dHaOpen0, dHaClose0)

        dHaGreen0 = dHaClose0 > dHaOpen0
        dHaRed0 = dHaClose0 < dHaOpen0
        dNumRow = numRow        
        numRow = numRow + 1        
        df = pd.DataFrame({'numRow' : pd.Series(dNumRow), 'Time' : pd.Series(dTime0), 'Date' : pd.Series(dDate0), 'Ticker' : pd.Series(dTicker0), 'Open0' : pd.Series(dOpen0), 'High0' : pd.Series(dHigh0), 'Low0' : pd.Series(dLow0), 'Close0' : pd.Series(dClose0)})
        #print df
        df.to_csv('C:\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\HaDetail.csv')
```

any help hugely appreciated. Im new to python and learning on the job..

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why don't you just create the df you want to write out and just do `to_csv`? with what you're doing you're overwriting your csv on each iteration so only the last iteration will be written

Comment: Hi, I was hoping to index using numRow, make calculations on data in mkt_data, create dataframe and save to csv. is "df" above and "df.to_csv" creating a df and write it out as you suggested?. the bit thats confusing me is I can see the df when I print it out. sample below. I suspect the 0 down the left are the problem...
 Close0        Date     High0    Low0     Open0 Ticker   Time  numRow
0  178.78  02/01/2015  178.7943  178.68  178.7099    DIA  14:32       2
0  178.89  02/01/2015  178.89  178.77  178.795    DIA  14:33       3

Comment: The fact remains, unless you pass `mode='a'` then you're overwriting the csv on each iteration so it looks like you're writing the headers so you want to write the header on first iteration and then pass `header=False` and `mode='a'` for each subsequent iteration

Comment: thank you , that worked a treat.. i will read up some more on dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your csv on each iteration because the default `mode` is `'w'` which will overwrite if it exists, additionally you are writing out your header and you only need to do this on the first iteration so I would do the following:

```
Index_tickers = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\\Index_list\\Index_tickers.csv')
Ticker = Index_tickers.ticker
writeHeader = True


for ticker in Index_tickers.ticker:    
    index_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\\Index_list\\' + ticker + '_1.csv')
    mkt_data = index_data[['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
    numRow = 2

    while numRow < endRow:
        dOpen0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Open']
        dHigh0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'High']
        dLow0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Low']
        dClose0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Close']
        dDate0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Date']
        dTime0 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, 'Time']
        dTicker0 = index_data.ix[numRow, 'Ticker']

        dHaClose0 = (dOpen0 + dHigh0 + dLow0 + dClose0) / 4
        dClose1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow -2  , 'Close']
        dOpen1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow -2  , 'Open']
        dHaOpen0 = (dClose1 + dOpen1) / 2 
        dHaHigh0 = max(dHigh0, dHaOpen0, dHaClose0)
        dHaLow0 = min(dLow0, dHaOpen0, dHaClose0)

        dHaGreen0 = dHaClose0 > dHaOpen0
        dHaRed0 = dHaClose0 < dHaOpen0
        dNumRow = numRow        
        numRow = numRow + 1        
        df = pd.DataFrame({'numRow' : pd.Series(dNumRow), 'Time' : pd.Series(dTime0), 'Date' : pd.Series(dDate0), 'Ticker' : pd.Series(dTicker0), 'Open0' : pd.Series(dOpen0), 'High0' : pd.Series(dHigh0), 'Low0' : pd.Series(dLow0), 'Close0' : pd.Series(dClose0)})
        #print df
        if writeHeader:
            df.to_csv('C:\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\HaDetail.csv')
            writeHeader = False
        else:
            df.to_csv('C:\Users\\ME\\Dropbox\\MktData\HaDetail.csv', header=False, mode='a')
```

So we only write the header on first iteration and then for each subsequent iteration change the `mode` to `'a'` so it appends to the file, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)